# Индикатив или сослагательное наклонение?

Tags: наклонение

Что бы Вы сказали: это простой индикатив или сослагательное наклонение? (*бы* в составе *что* + глагольная форма на -*л*) Здесь функционирует правило "cослагательное наклонение в относительных придаточных под отрицанием"?

*Ему не надо было ежедневно для памяти делать зарубки на стене камеры, потому что и дня не проходило без того, **чтобы** что-либо **не напомнило** ему о ней.*

Спасибо!

Comment: Не может быть простой индикатив.  Если был бы индикатив, то значение было бы другое. "Не напомнило" - отрицание.  Так что сослагательное, никуда не денешься...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

...и дня не проходило без того, чтобы что-либо не напомнило ему о ней.

Это СПП с приместоименным изъяснительным придаточным (вмещающее СПП). Союз ЧТОБЫ при сочетании с формой глагола на -Л обозначает **ирреальную модальность**, обозначающую привычную последовательностью событий.

**Сравнить:**

День начался с того, что они поссорились (**изъявительное** наклонение).

Ни дня не проходит, чтобы они не поссорились (**сослагательное** наклонение, предлог БЕЗ, отрицание  в обеих частях).

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы,это  собственно сослагательное наклонение -  сочетание прошедшего времени с союзом чтобы (чтоб).

В сочетании с частицей бы (б), в том числе в составе союза чтобы форма прошедшего времени теряет свою исходную функцию обозначения ситуации, имевшей место до момента речи, гипотетические относительные придаточные  обозначают свойства отрицаемой ситуации или объекта.

Вот похожие примеры:

Сегодня нет ни одной ежедневной газеты, которая бы не была откровенным подручным мэра или губернатора. [«Отечественные записки», 2003]

Не было какого-нибудь события в жизни Соколовых, в котором самое сердечное участие не принимали бы Вадим и жена его Алла ― «мастер халата».  http://rusgram.ru/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#342